# How do i replace spaces with +'s in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sdk, ios-4.2

I am building an app with a lot of urls being called from a MySQL server.

What I need to do for my app is take the textfield text and send it (which i already know how to do) BUT i need to replace the spaces with + (pluses)

Comment: What you *probably* need to do is URL encode the text, not take a piecemeal approach where you encode spaces as + signs, then find the next character that's also illegal. I've found a [blog post](http://madebymany.com/blog/url-encoding-an-nsstring-on-ios) that describes doing so under iOS.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I +1'd you because you're right about the URL encoding, but you should provide an answer here in addition to linking to the blog post =)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try with the string method `- (NSString *)stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:(NSString *)target withString:(NSString *)replacement;`

```
str=[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
```

Comment: This is what you want, except you want to replace it with a @"+", not a @"".