# How to replace spaces with + in string with format

Tags: ios, xcode, string, replace, space

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do i replace spaces with +'s in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7284380/how-do-i-replace-spaces-with-s-in-xcode)

In this string I need to replace spaces:

```
controller.body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=%@@%@,%@", pinTitle.text, newlatLabel.text, newlogLabel.text];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7284380/581194 (vote to close)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like:

```
NSString *finalString = [controller.body stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString: @"+"];
```

---

```
controller.body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=%@@%@,%@", pinTitle.text, newlatLabel.text, newlogLabel.text];

NSString *finalString = [controller.body stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString: @"+"];

controller.body = finalString;
```

Comment: where I put variable "finalString"?

Comment: You could then do: `controller.body = finalString;` if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Think you are looking for this:

```
  NSString *finalString = [controller.body stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
```